# Dirty form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, jquery-dirtyforms

i wanted to monitor the  forms for change and alerts the user before leaving the page. so i used a dirty form plugin [found here](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms)

this is the code i tried

form

```
  <?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use app\models\Countries;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Organizations */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?>/css/userHome.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.dirtyforms/2.0.0-beta00005/jquery.dirtyforms.min.js"></script>
<div class="organizations-form">
    <h2>Update Billing Address</h2><br>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset2">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_address')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_country_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Countries::find()
    ->all(), 'id', 'name'),['prompt'=>'Choose a Country'])->label('Select Country')  ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_state')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_city')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_postal')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>



    <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_mobile')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>



    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
</div>
```

script used

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

    // Enable on all forms
    $('form').dirtyForms();
});
</script>
```

now if i try to go to other pages or link without saving i get popup meassege. But when i try to submit message even then the popup is appearing.
why is that so?

Comment: provide relevent html please?

Comment: post the rendered HTML

Comment: the code that i have given by the heading form is the view which has the form and it is the page which is getting rendered. its a yii2 code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use app\models\Countries;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Organizations */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?>/css/userHome.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.dirtyforms/2.0.0-beta00005/jquery.dirtyforms.min.js"></script>
<div class="organizations-form">
    <h2>Update Billing Address</h2><br>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset2">
        <div class="ignore">


    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_address')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_country_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Countries::find()
    ->all(), 'id', 'name'),['prompt'=>'Choose a Country'])->label('Select Country')  ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_state')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_city')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_postal')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>



    <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_mobile')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>



    <div class="form-group ">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-success' ,'id'=>'update']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

    // Enable on all forms
    $('form').dirtyForms();
    $('#update').click(function(){ 
    $('.ignore').addClass($.DirtyForms.ignoreClass);
        });


});
</script>
```

i checked whether the button is clicked. if yes then i used the ignore function in dirty form to the whole form(which is in div class="ignore") so when i click the button to submit there will be no popup's.

Comment: A few words would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

> But when i try to submit message even then the popup is appearing. why is that so?

Dirty Forms attempts to ignore when a submit happens by using an `<input type="submit">` tag. However, with JavaScript it is also possible to submit a form by clicking other types of form tags (such as anchor tags).

Dirty Forms by default will interpret any anchor tag click as an attempt to navigate from the page. If you are using some JavaScript widget that uses anchor tags for other purposes, you can ignore them by putting them in the `ignoreSelector`, adding the `ignoreClass`, or putting them inside of a container element with the `ignoreClass`. See [ignoring things](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms#ignoring-things) for details.